# Is there a way to customize the services in the direct contact shortcut?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, customization, contact-shortcut

I added a contact shortcut to my home screen, and I noticed that the Messaging icon in the pop-up changed to Handcent when I changed the default messaging app on my phone. One thing that's always bothered me is that there's a Facebook icon in the pop-up. Is there any way to customize what pops up when you press on a contact shortcut?

Comment: My guess is that it will either require root access or will fall into the category that my question about customizing the "Share" popup, un-customizable even with root (at least thats what the consensus was).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stop syncing Facebook with your phone book, that option will disappear.  I realize this isn't an answer to your question about customizing the pop-up but it may just serve your needs until a more skilled Android ninja happens upon this question.

Comment: I've never synced Facebook with my phone book.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it, but one of the Android updates must have turned on Facebook sync in my contacts. It has now been removed.

Answer (score 0):

What phone make and model do you have? What version of Android? What are you doing to add the shortcut for the contact?

If I go to add a shortcut after long clicking on the homescreen I get an option for "Person". Then I choose the individual to make a shortcut for and I have the option of some things to add for that shortcut. If you choose contact card or quick contact you get a decent amount of options. Contact card gives you everything for that contact. Not as many options as you might want sure, but whatever you select from the contact card will use the phone default.

Comment: As I said in the question, its a shortcut to a contact. Long press, add shortcut, contact. Phone make doesn't matter. Version 2.2.

Comment: Phone does matter which is why I was asking. Different phones use different launchers and different contact systems which changes the answer. If you have an HTC phone then chances are you have HTC Sense running and I would have an easy time helping you as I have an HTC phone running an HTC based ROM. If you are not using an HTC phone or are not using HTC based ROM I could still help you but would need to load my non HTC based ROM. Since you say you selected Contact after choosing shortcut I'm guessing you are using a non HTC phone. Correct?